# Firefox Mobile-specific CSS

Tags: css, firefox, mobile, fennec

I've been testing a mobile version of my website on the Android browser. The way I do it is with:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {  [my mobile CSS] }
```

Now, I've started to test it out in the Firefox Mobile beta, and there's one specific element which I can't get to look right in both the stock browser and Firefox; stock requires margin-left: 23% (which Firefox renders too far right), and Firefox requires margin-left: 30% (which stock renders too far left). I've experimented with px values, and the same problem occurs.

So, what I've tried to do is:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
[my mobile CSS]
@-moz-document url-prefix([the domain]){ [Firefox Mobile adjustment] }
}
```

This doesn't work.

If I put the @-moz-document rule  outside of the @media rule, it works perfectly, but affects desktop Firefox as well as mobile. Nesting @media inside of @-moz-document, though, doesn't.

Is there any working way to target only Firefox Mobile with CSS?

Comment: The problem here is that Firefox can't seem to figure out nested at-rules like that :/

Answer (score 1):

use

```
@media (-moz-touch-enabled){
    //style for FF with touch
}
```

Comment: Consider describing the code so that one can get a clear idea about it.

Comment: This works only until FF mobile 73. At least in Firefox mobile beta (80), "-moz-touch-enabled" is not supported anymore,

Comment: This doesn't work on FF 110.1.0 Android

Answer (score 1):

This now seems to work with the relatively new `pointer` media query:

```css
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    @media (pointer:coarse) {
        /* styles */
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work on FF 110.1.0 Android

Answer (score 0):

BoltClock seems to be right. There's no way to do this with just CSS.

I had to put this `<script>` in my page's `<head>`:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Fennec') != -1) { 
document.write('<style>
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
#sharebox{ margin-left:-30%;}
}</style>');}
```

That worked.

Comment: you should use `'ontouchend' in document` in your `if` statement

Answer (score 0):

This worked **perfectly** for me.

```
 @media only screen and (min-width:320px){ // media query 
     @-moz-document url-prefix() { // target FF
         .selector { // Voila
             my: styles;
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: This targets mobile and desktop ff.